# ResultSet.getDate() returning wrong date

Tags: java, mysql, date, jodatime

I am having a problem using the `ResultSet.getDate()` method. I have a date field in MySQL and when I try to get the value, the date obtained is today's date instead of the date in the table specified. I don't know what is causing this error, I have searched other posts, but other errors with `getDate()` were different, like parsing or data mismatch errors or other kinds of errors. It could be an error due to time zone, because the values of the dates are from yesterday, but there's one row with date of two days ago and it's also returning today's date.

Here's the code:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import model.Paciente;
import teste.ConnectionFactory;

public class PacienteDao {


    // a conexão com o banco de dados
    private Connection connection;

    public PacienteDao() {
        this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }

    public void adiciona(Paciente paciente) {
        String sql = "insert into paciente" +
                " (nome_paciente,cpf_paciente,rg_paciente,data_nasc)" +

                "values (?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            stmt.setString(1, paciente.getNome_paciente());
            stmt.setString(2, paciente.getCpf());
            stmt.setString(3, paciente.getRg());

            java.sql.Date data_nasc = new java.sql.Date(paciente.getData_nasc().toDate().getTime());
            stmt.setDate(4, data_nasc);

            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public List<Paciente> listaPacientes() {

        List<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();

        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("select * from paciente");

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
                paciente.setId_paciente(rs.getInt("id_paciente"));
                paciente.setNome_paciente(rs.getString("nome_paciente"));
                paciente.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf_paciente"));
                paciente.setRg(rs.getString("rg_paciente"));

                LocalDate dt = new LocalDate();
                dt.fromDateFields(rs.getDate("data_nasc"));
                paciente.setData_nasc(dt);

                pacientes.add(paciente);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pacientes;
    }
```

Here's the data that should be returned (CSV):

- "1","Lucas","1111111111","12222222","2017-12-19"
- "2","Lucas","1111111111","12222222","2017-12-20"
- "3","Lucas","1111111111","12222222","2017-12-20"
- "4","Leandro","2321","21232","2017-12-20"

Here's the data that is been returned (StackTrace):

Id: 1
Nome: Lucas
CPF: 1111111111
RG: 12222222
Data de Nascimento: 2017-12-21

Id: 2
Nome: Lucas
CPF: 1111111111
RG: 12222222
Data de Nascimento: 2017-12-21

Id: 3
Nome: Lucas
CPF: 1111111111
RG: 12222222
Data de Nascimento: 2017-12-21

Id: 4
Nome: Leandro
CPF: 2321
RG: 21232
Data de Nascimento: 2017-12-21

Like I said one of the rows has a date of two days ago, but it's showing today's date too, so I think isn't a time zone error.

PS: The name of the variables and methods are in Portuguese, because the application is in Portuguese too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
LocalDate dt = new LocalDate();
dt.fromDateFields(rs.getDate("data_nasc"));
```

The first statement creates a new `LocalDate` set to today.  The second statement is a call to the `static` method `fromDateFields`, which should have been flagged as a warning by your IDE an/or compiler. This method returns a ***new*** `LocalDate` object, which you discarded, and does not modify `dt`.  The above should be:

```
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.fromDateFields(rs.getDate("data_nasc"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933443/642706) is correct. The much simpler and more intuitive code seen below would have prevented that particular mistake.

In addition, you are:

- Ignoring the crucial issue of time zone in determining a date.
- Using an older library from a project that recommends you move to their modern replacement classes.

## tl;dr

Using java.time classes that replaced Joda-Time.

```
myResultSet().getObject( … , Instant.class )         // Extract a moment on the timeline in UTC, an `Instant` object.
             .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )  // Adjust into a time zone, to determine a date, rendering a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
             .toLocalDate()                          // Extract a date-only object, a `LocalDate` without time-of-day and without a time zone.
```

## Avoid legacy classes

You should not be using `PreparedStatement::getDate()`. Avoid all of the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, such as Date, Calendar, and the related java.sql types. These are entirely supplanted with the java.time classes and a JDBC 4.2 driver.

Likewise, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its team advises migration to the java.time which they inspired, defined, and implemented in JSR 310.

## java.time

Use `getObject` and `setObject` methods.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet().getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;  // For retrieving a standard SQL `DATE` column.
```

And…

```
myPrepatedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

That code above is for a standard SQL `DATE` column which is a date-only value.

But it sounds like you have a moment stored, perhaps the MySQL type `TIMESTAMP` which seems to track with the standard SQL `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type. Any provided offset or time zone info is used to adjust the value into UTC upon submission to the database, in MySQL, with a resolution of microseconds.

So the equivalent type in Java is `Instant`, for a point in the timeline in UTC but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

And…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Remember that the `Instant` is always in UTC. But determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

From there extract the date-only object that seems to be your goal.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```